# import sqoop to hdfs error Application failed 2 times due to AM Container

Tags: hadoop, import, sqoop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrRlv.png)

I try to import data using sqoop
cmd :

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.26.8:1717;databasename=VMC" -- table contact -m 1 --username sa --password 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory
```

You need to install Java correctly on all nodes in the cluster, including setting JAVA_HOME in the hadoop-env.sh file